# VOLTAGE DROP IN WIFI MODULE

Tags: embedded, hardware

I am using esp8266 the with atmega32a, the modules operates on 3.3V . However, when I use the voltage regulator Lm317 and adjust the voltage to 3.3V and then I connect the module to the output of the regulator the output voltage of the regulator decreases to 2.6v, why is this happening?

Is this normal as the esp draws a lot of current? or is there other problem? and the module is not responding to any AT commands.

[image: schematic]

Comment: It would be good if you could draw a copy of your schematic using the tool. Also what are you using to supply your voltage to the regulator?

Comment: a power supply that gives 12 and 5 volts with maximum 2A  , and when I connect it to the circuit current is 450mA so I think it is working well

Comment: is your regulator getting hot?

Comment: yes , actually I tried something I put the 5v power supply directly to the module and found that that the the voltage dropped from 5.2 to 3.6 ...then I tried something else . I tested the connectivity between the vcc and the ground of the module and found that the are connected ( the buzzer worked) so maybe there is a short happened and I should get a new one

Answer (score 2):

The ESP8266 current requiremnts are as follows: 
[image]

If your Lm317 is working correctly then it should be able to supply this current without any problems.
You need to ensure your input voltage is at least 6.3 V (minimum Vin - Vout for the LM317 is 3 V). (There is also a minimum requirement of 10 mA so you won't be able to achieve low current such as when the ESP8266 and the driving microprocessor are in sleep modes)

You should be able to test your regulator with a 15 Ohm resistor. If this works you likely have a bad ESP8266 ....if the voltage drops below 3.3 V you have a problem with your regulator.

Comment: If the LM317's minimum input/output voltage differential is 3 volts, the input must be above 6.3 volts to ensure 3.3 volts at the output.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put 20 pounds of stuff in a 10 pound bag.

It seems your power supply can't handle the current demand of this WiFi module.  Perhaps it's more than the regulator can output.  Or, it could be more than whatever is feeding the regulator can output.  One way or the other, you're asking for more current from some power supply than it can deliver.

The first step in diagnosing this is to see what happens to the input voltage of this LM317 regulator.  If it collapses too, then the upstream supply can't handle the load.  If it's still high enough to be within the spec of the LM317, then the current is more than the LM317 can handle, at least how you've wired it.  You may also have a bug in how the regulator is wired.

Comment: LM317 is supposed to be able to source 1.25A

Comment: @AliMak That depends on your supply behind the LM317 being able to supply that plus the limitation of voltage drop times current across your LM317. Read the datasheet.

Comment: yes , actually I tried something I put the 5v power supply directly to the module and found that that the the voltage dropped from 5.2 to 3.6 ...then I tried something else . I tested the connectivity between the vcc and the ground of the module and found that the are connected ( the buzzer worked) so maybe there is a short happened and I should get a new one, which do you think caused the problem?

Comment: @AliMak The current kind of depends on what package you use. Sure the spec is 1.5A but that is at Temp to junction 25 degrees C, so it assumes that you have sufficient cooling, as the part itself will get hot. Meaning that in practice, to TO-220 through-hole package might be able to deliver more current than the SO-223 package, because the former has better thermal characteristics and is far easier to cool down. Upon overheating the regulator, it will do thermal shut-down and the output voltage will drop. Which LM317 package are you using?